# API Triggered Send in MC/ExactTarget resulting in Error Code 13 cannot match Subscriber Key for only one subscriber?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

Using SOAP API to trigger sends from ExactTarget. Testing has been working with exception of one email/subscriber in which we always receive error code 13 every time. Confirmed SK matches in system with email address. Have removed subscriber, cleared DE, and the added again. Testes various triggers via API and still get error.

Any idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

As per the list of error codes in the email send link: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/email_messages/email_send_error_codes/ , error code 13 corresponds to: "The subscriber key in the Salesforce Marketing Cloud system does not match the subscriber key provided"

The error might have occurred if your mailing list has the same mailing address repeating twice and the mail address has already been inserted with a different subscriber key or the mailing address is already available in the all subscriber list with a different subscriber key.

Since you have deleted the subscriber and tried, it should be the first case.  Check your list if the mailing address is repeated with different subscriber keys.